# efficient equi join in Q

Tags: kdb, q-lang

How do I optimize equijoin? Table 1 has 500000 rows, Table 2 has 200,000 rows and I need to do equi join between them. The resulting table should have about 20,000,000 rows. It takes about 20 seconds currently to run -

```
ej[`key;Table1;Table2]
```

I tried some attributes on the 'key' column to no avail.

Comment: Is it really that slow? Can you show the output of `meta Table1` and `meta Table2` please? On my average-spec machine `ej` on some random data runs in approximately 1 second resulting in 24,413,284 rows.

Answer (score 0):

In case if one of your tables has primary key and join is made on this primary key, then `lj` should give better results than `ej`. I would suggest to try

```
    Table1 lj `key xkey Table2
```

Also key type is important. In case if key is `char[]` it is worth to cast it to symbol before joining.

Comment: I know left join will be much faster but I need equi join to get all matching pairs in the two tables. The keys are symbols or integers.

Comment: In case if none of the them has primary key I would propose to apply grouping to each of them or both and compare the results then. Like `ej['key;Table1;update 'g#key from Table2]` or ej['key;update 'g#key from Table1;update 'g#key from Table2]`. (in code "backtick" was replaced by ', please, replace back for testing)

Answer (score 0):

Equi-join `ej` is essentially the same as [inner-join `ij`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#ij-ijf-inner-join) but accepts the key columns as a parameter. You could instead try `ij`, keying the right hand table:

```
Table1 ij `key xkey Table2
```

Which should improve performance.